# Rspec metadata: vcr should only kick in for tagged examples, but works for every example instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vcr

Simple setup:

```
#spec_helper.rb

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = File.expand_path '../vcr_cassettes', __FILE__
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
end
```

I am expecting examples not tagged with `:vcr` to not be affected but that does not seem to be the case. I am getting "VCR does not know about request..." kind of error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

VCR is designed to help you identify all places in your test suite where HTTP requests are made and to help you get them under deterministic test.  As such, by default, when an HTTP request is made and no cassette is in use, it raises an error.  You can [configure](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/allow-http-connections-when-no-cassette!) it to allow HTTP connections when there is no cassette if you prefer.